# Listen for changes in a list child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my database I store user messages. Each message can be liked/unliked. On web-client I want to listen for `likes` changes. I can't quite figure out how it's done.

Here's database structure:

```
{
  "messages": {
    ".write": true
    "$messageId": {
      likes: { ".validate": true }
      text: { ".validate": true }
    }
  }
}
```

If I was using cloud functions I'd subscribe like this:

```
exports.tags = functions.database.ref('/messages/{id}/likes')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const newValue = event.data.val()
    ....
  })
```

In other words I need to get a message object whenever it's `likes` value changes. Any advice?

Comment: You also might consider using a Redux pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set observer for message table as below code

```
messageRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
  setCommentValues(postElement, data.key, data.val().text, data.val().author);
});
```

And to do needful in the body of function.

Comment: In Cloud Functions please use `once()` instead of `on()`, since the latter will keep a listener active for longer than needed (and just possibly transfer more data at a higher cost).

Comment: but once will fire get once like is changed. If it's again changed this will not fire and web code will not made aware for it.

Comment: @sschunara, It works if I know `messageId` in advance. For example, `database.ref('/messages/AGvoxWCVUgVAzr4tVu06tRftAVw1')`. Is there a way to do the same without knowing `messageId`?

Comment: @sschunara, oh, I figured it out, there was an issue with rules, thanks man!

Comment: @sschunara Correct, the child hasn't changed and it may not even change before the function times out. You'll want to listen for `value` instead: `event.data.ref.parent.once('value', ...`. See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data